# Paperclip preserves animated GIFs - how to tell it to stop doing this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

So, I don't want to generate animated thumbnails. Is there an easy way to explain this to paperclip?

**Upd.**

Of course, there's an option of converting animations to jpeg. But for me this results in a very inefficient ImageMagic command (looks like it's processing every frame to generate a flat image in the end). It's especially frustrating and time consuming for big gifs.

Also, converting a gif to another format when I only need to extract the first frame simply doesn't feel right to me. After all, I do not want to switch format.

As @faron commented bellow, ImageMagic has special syntax to select a frame from a sequence: `convert animation.gif[0] frame0.gif`. What I really want to find is a way to instruct paperclip to use this syntax.

Comment: Is saving the thumbnails with `:format => :jpg` an option?

Comment: Maybe post the issue here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues. Not what you are looking for?

Comment: If you are using `ImageMagick` you can add custom processing with smth like `convert animation.gif[0] frame0.gif` (see [thread in imagemagick forum](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=10541))

Comment: @Stefan, I updated the question to explain, why I don't like converting to another format

Comment: @faron, you're right, but I'd like to do this with paperclip

Answer (score 2):

The solution turned out to be quite simple. There's an `animated` option that can be passed to the [Paperclip::Thumbnail](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/thumbnail.rb) processor. If `animated` option is false, Paperclip knows that you want only the first frame from an animation. Example:

```ruby
has_attached_file :pic,
  styles: {
    large: { geometry: "700>", animated: false },
    thumb: { geometry: "280>", animated: false },
  }, 
  ...
```